# Ruby/Regex parsing strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to take a string and split it into an array only if its format is valid

Valid formats for the string include:

- `key: Bob value: 5000`
- `key: Jane value: 6000,700,100`

An invalid format, besides `key:` or `value:` being spelled wrong:

- `key: Bob value: 6000,,,,100`

I've been using `gets` to get a line and trying to use this code:

```
if line =~ /key:\s\d+\svalue:\s([\d+]+,?)*/
 # do stuff
end
```

I also tried using `===` but both just return true / not nil for both valid and invalid strings. How can I ensure that multiple consecutive commas is considered invalid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

["affirmative" match](https://regex101.com/r/qP6vW8/1#pcre):

`^key:\s\w+\svalue:\s(\d+,?)+$ //better validation`

["negative" match](https://regex101.com/r/qP6vW8/2):

`^(?!.*,,).*$ //simple negative lookahead`

Comment: Curious: Why does the ^ $ make such a big difference?

Comment: they force the regex to span the entire input string... http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: `^` and `$` don't mean beginning/ending of string in Ruby, they mean beginning/ending of *line*. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` in Ruby.

Comment: You want `# better validation`. Ruby does not support `//` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use split in situations like this:

```
str = "key: Bob value: 5000,330,200"
 => "key: Bob value: 5000,330,200" 

arr = str.split
 => ["key:", "Bob", "value:", "5000,330,200"] 

if arr[0] == "key:" && arr[2] == "value:" && arr[3].split(",").none?(&:empty?)
  # do stuff
end
```

Easier for me to suss out.

Comment: Consider `key, value, *numbers = str.split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/)`, then `if key == "key:" && value == "value:" && numbers.none?(&:empty?)`.

Comment: @CareySwoveland - Thanks, fixed.